# Node and Mongo - Multiple collection calls in one method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, methods

I have these collections:

**Sessao:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a450a30ca4b001587fcf967"),
    "cliente" : ObjectId("5a1407c8099ca208e48170a5"),
    "data" : "28/12/2017",
    "numero" : "11",
    "dadosORS" : ObjectId("5a4507d451c2c614a788c120"),
    "dadosSRS" : ObjectId("5a465bcbca4b001587fcf968")
}
```

**registosORS:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a450a30ca4b001587fcf966"),
    "sessao" : "11",
    "outroResponsavel" : "",
    "relacao" : "",
    "valorIndividualmente" : "1",
    "valorInterpessoal" : "1",
    "valorSocialmente" : "1",
    "valorGlobalmente" : "1",
    "email" : "as@uminho.pt",
    "data" : "28/12/2017",
    "somaValoresOrs" : 4
}
```

**and registosSRS:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a465bcbca4b001587fcf968"),
    "sessao" : "11",
    "valorRelacao" : "7.18",
    "valorObjectivo" : "5.06",
    "valorAbordagem" : "5.18",
    "valorGeral" : "5.37",
    "cliente_id" : "5a1407c8099ca208e48170a5",
    "email" : "as@uminho.pt",
    "somaValoresSrs" : 22.79,
    "data" : "29/12/2017"
}
```

Now, I need to list all the sessions for a given cliente_id, as well as the ORS and SRS data.

I'm doing a function in the model to list this information, but this isn't working. I thought I could search for all the sessions of that clienteid, and then using the  dadosORS and dadosSRS id's, I could create an array with these data, but the arrays are undefined outside the for.

```
ClientesDAO.prototype.dadosORSSRSSession = function(clienteid, callback){
    var client_id = new ObjectId.ObjectID(clienteid);

    this._connection.open(function(err,mongoClient){
        mongoClient.collection('sessao', function(err,collection){
             collection.find({cliente:client_id}).toArray(function(err,result){

                // console.log('result find das sessoes');
                // console.log(result);
                var ORS_id = [];
                var ORS_cliente = [];
                var SRS_id = [];
                var SRS_cliente = [];

                for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++){

                        ORS_id[i] = new ObjectId.ObjectID(result[i].dadosORS);

                        mongoClient.collection('registosORS', function(err,collection){
                             collection.find({_id:ORS_id[i]}).toArray(function(err,result){
                                    ORS_cliente.push(result[0])
                            })
                        })

                        SRS_id[i] = new ObjectId.ObjectID(result[i].dadosSRS);

                        mongoClient.collection('registosSRS', function(err,collection){
                             collection.find({_id:SRS_id[i]}).toArray(function(err,result){
                                    SRS_cliente.push(result[0])
                            })
                        })
                }   

                console.log('result ORS');
                console.log(ORS_cliente);
                console.log('result SRS');
                console.log(SRS_cliente);

                mongoClient.close();

            })
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could create an array with these data, but the arrays are undefined outside the for.

This is because db calls are asynchronous.

You can use `Promise` and `async` [`eachOf`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOf) to collect the details in an array.

```
'use strict';

let _ = require('lodash');
let async = require('async');

ClientesDAO.prototype.dadosORSSRSSession = function (clienteid, callback) {
  var client_id = new ObjectId.ObjectID(clienteid);

  this._connection.open(function (err, mongoClient) {

    mongoClient.collection('sessao', function (err, collection) {

      if (err) {
        console.log('err when establishing db connection', err);
        return;
      }

      collection.find({
        cliente: client_id
      }).toArray(function (err, result) {

        async.forEachOf(result, function (value, key, callback) {

          let orsId = new ObjectId.ObjectID(value.dadosORS);
          let srsId = new ObjectId.ObjectID(value.dadosSRS);

          Promise.all([
            getORSDetailsById(mongoClient, orsId),
            getSRSDetailsById(mongoClient, srsId)
          ]).then((results) => {
            callback(null, {
              ors_id: orsId,
              srs_id: srsId,
              ors: results[0],
              srs: results[1]
            })
          }).catch((err) => {
            callback(err);
          });

        }, function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            return console.error(err.message);
          }

          let orsIds = _.map(result, (item) => {
            return item.ors_id;
          });

          let srsIds = _.map(result, (item) => {
            return item.srs_id;
          });

          let orsCliente = _.map(result, (item) => {
            return item.ors;
          });


          let srsCliente = _.map(result, (item) => {
            return item.srs;
          });

          console.log('orsIds', orsIds);
          console.log('srsIds', srsIds);
          console.log('orsCliente', orsCliente);
          console.log('srsCliente', srsCliente);

        });

        mongoClient.close();

      });
    });
  });

};


function getORSDetailsById(mongoClient, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoClient.collection('registosORS', function (err, collection) {
      collection.find({
        _id: id
      }).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(result[0]);
      })
    });
  });
}

function getSRSDetailsById(mongoClient, id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoClient.collection('registosSRS', function (err, collection) {
      collection.find({
        _id: id
      }).toArray(function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(result[0]);
      })
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I will read..but before, I've installed the async and lodash modules but when I run your code it says: mongoClient is not defined ..

Comment: I've updated the answer for any possible error, could please check now

Comment: The problem is that in getORSDetailsById and getSRSDetailsById we do not have mongoClient as parameter like in ClientesDAO.prototype.dadosORSSRSSession

Comment: Sorry, missed it. Added now

Comment: It was it, no erros now, but the results are empty: orsIds [], srsIds [], orsCliente [], srsCliente []

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162153/discussion-between-efo-and-sridhar).

Answer (score 0):

the arrays are undefined outside the for because they are asynchronous, db operation do not block, use event avoid that.

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter { }
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

myEmitter.on('myEvent', () => {
    console.log('result ORS');
    console.log(ORS_cliente);
    console.log('result SRS');
    console.log(SRS_cliente);
})

for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
    ORS_id[i] = new ObjectId.ObjectID(result[i].dadosORS);
    mongoClient.collection('registosORS', function(err,collection){
         collection.find({_id:ORS_id[i]}).toArray(function(err,result){
                ORS_cliente.push(result[0])
        })
    })

    SRS_id[i] = new ObjectId.ObjectID(result[i].dadosSRS);
    mongoClient.collection('registosSRS', function(err,collection){
         collection.find({_id:SRS_id[i]}).toArray(function(err,result){
                SRS_cliente.push(result[0])
        })
    })

    if (i == result.length-1) {
        myEmitter.emit('myEvent');
    }
}
```

more info about asynchronous controll , suggest you see promise and async/await .

Comment: Where should I put the 'on' event? Actually I need to return a function with this data.